# Appending a list to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append, element

In the following code, I am trying to append a list called a to a list of lists b.

```
a = [5,4]
b = [[4],[3],[8]]
b[2].append(a)
```

Python outputs

```
[[4], [3], [8, [5, 4]]]
```

However, I want the elements to be appended as integers not as a list so b should be [[4], [3], [8, 5, 4]] and then I want to merge the lists so b would be [4, 3, 8, 5, 4]. I want to be able to do this so I can use the sum function to find the sum of b's elements. Does anyone have suggestions regarding how this can be done?

Comment: Did you mean: ‘b[2].extend(a)’ ?

Comment: `[8]+[5,4]` yields `[8,5,4]`, so you could do `b[2] += a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are trying to *extend* a list, not append to it. Specifically, you want to do

```
b[2].extend(a)
```

`append()` adds a single element to a list. `extend()` adds many elements to a list. `extend()` accepts any iterable object, not just lists. But it's most common to pass it a list.

Once you have your desired list-of-lists, e.g.

```
[[4], [3], [8, 5, 4]]
```

then you need to concatenate those lists to get a flat list of ints. You can use `sum()` for that -- adding lists is not that different from adding ints.

```
b = sum(b, [])
```

The trick here is that you have to pass the initial (empty) value to `sum()`, otherwise it tries to add the lists in `b` as though they were numbers.

Finally, you can sum the flattened list as you intended:

```
sum(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the **chain** function taken from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) builtin package to achieve your goal in a more concise and pythonic way.

Just one line of code is needed:

```
sum(chain(a, tuple(chain.from_iterable(b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want a list full of integers -not a list with lists of integers-.
Anyways I'll try to give a solution for both of them.

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[-1].append(a[i])
```

Outputs: `b = [[4], [3], [8, 5, 4]]`

or maybe just every number in one list:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append([a[i]])
```

Outputs: `b = [[4], [3], [8], [5], [4]]`